# How to add CSS styling in Mapbox GL Popup?

Tags: web-mapping, mapbox, cartocss, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am aware this is similar to many other questions, but I have been unable to determine how to add the correct code to style my popups in mapbox-gl. I'm very new to CSS, Mapbox-gl, and coding in general. I would like to be able to add banners, change the colors and fonts of different sections, and other additions. I've read [this](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.1.1/l-popup/) and several posts on SE, which pointed me in the right direction, however I have still been unable to make this work.

Here is a sample of my code - I think I know where I am doing something wrong but I am not sure what to do right.

```
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title>Points on a map</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.31.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.31.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  #map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
   mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2RpY2tpbnNvbjExIiwiYSI6ImNqZThwZGg1dDAyMngzM3Fsdmp0dm82YTcifQ.bjVqusaDZqdZVWunQ0xS7A'; // replace this with your access token
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/cdickinson11/cjfv618mp9uur2rohbhbp1yiy'
});

    map.on('click', function(e) {
  var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
    layers: ['masterdirectory-qc-v3'] // replace this with the name of the layer
```

});

```
  if (!features.length) {  return;
```

}

```
 var feature = features[0];

  var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: [0, -15] })
.setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
.setHTML('<h3>' + feature.properties.Company + '</h3><p>' + feature.properties.City + '</p>' + feature.properties.URL + '</p>')
.setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)

setContent(Popup.content {
color: #F3F3DD;
background-color: #F3F3DD;
border-color: #228B22;
max-width: 250px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #8B5D33;
font-family: 'Oswald';
```

})

```
.addTo(map);
```

});

```
</script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I've read [this](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.1.1/l-popup/) and several posts on SE, which pointed me in the right direction

Your link is pointing to the docs about `mapbox.js` which is different from `mapbox-gl.js`.

Docs for Mapbox GL JS: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#popup

There is an official Mapbox tutorial which shows also how to style a Mapbox GL JS popup using CSS: https://www.mapbox.com/help/building-a-store-locator/

The following screenshot is taken from [there](https://www.mapbox.com/help/building-a-store-locator/#define-interactivity-functions):

[image]

Comment: you can use closeButton:false to not create the close button ass opposed to hide it in the CSS:

mapboxgl.Popup({closeOnClick:false,closeButton:false})

Answer (score 12):

Mapbox GL JS:

If you need even more control over the styling of the popup (e.g. set background color for different types of popups), you can set a custom classname directly on the top level of the popup with:

JS:

```
new mapboxgl.Popup({ className: "apple-popup" })

new mapboxgl.Popup({ className: "banana-popup and-another-css-class" })
```

CSS:

```
/* change background and tip color to green */
.apple-popup .mapboxgl-popup-content {
  background-color: green;
}
.apple-popup .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
  border-top-color: green;
}

/* change background and tip color to yellow */
.banana-popup .mapboxgl-popup-content {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.banana-popup .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
  border-top-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: This approach should be accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: This was insanely helpful - thank you!!